# Pros and cons of having a workplace promotion policy vs just having employees figure it out?

Tags: promotion

I was recently hired to be a manager at a new company and during my onboarding I was told that there isn't really a promotion process here and it is expected that worthwhile employees will figure it out.

Is this an accurate perception? Do companies do better if they have promotion policies or do they do better if they have a more organic approach?

Comment: The question in your body can't be answered by us, we weren't there. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Welcome to Workplace.SE. Unfortunately the question as stated is off-topic here. All StackExchange pages are targeted at finding one objectively best answer to each question. It seems your question is looking for opinions and therefore will be closed. At the very least you must explain a specific goal you want to achieve, instead of a yes/no or "which one is better" question.

Comment: @Chris is it sufficient to seek out pros and cons? There seem to be questions like that here.

Comment: Pros and cons are often considered to invite opinion here, which is off topic. Maybe "Is letting people figure out how to progress in the company by themselves considered as a profesional way to reward capable employe ?" I can't find a better way to phrase it (my english is rough).

Comment: I suspect that promotion policies just encourage people to chase KPIs, and hamstring the company from deciding to elevate the best people for the job.

Comment: While I do agree that this could be argued to be opinion-based, this is actually a really good question, though ideally any given answer would need to be backed up by some concrete data. I'm of the opinion that we should err on the side of not prematurely closing this question.

Comment: The edit improved it already, still you should be more specific about the goal. Better in which regard? E.g better for employee satisfaction, revenue, HR costs, ...?

Comment: Welcome new user.  Is this software related?

Comment: "Do companies do better..." - Note: we don't really do surveys or cite research here, which may be required to provide a good answer to that question. The recommendations given in the top-voted answers are assumed to be best in most cases, and they ideally also provide a solid argument for why that's best (or when it wouldn't be best). I think asking for pros and cons is fine, although you can probably also just ask whether it's better to have a promotion policy or to just let employees figure it out.

Answer (score 27):

> Pros and cons of having a workplace promotion policy vs just having employees figure it out?

**Just figure it out - Pros:**

- (Employer) Can give employees more responsibility without giving them a promotion or pay rise
- (Employer) Save money by hiring less staff and overworking current employees
- (Employer) Don't need to waste time with performance review meetings
- (Employer) Don't have to promote anyone
- (Employer) Can choose who to promote on a whim

There isn't a single pro for the employee. Lack of career progression opportunities is one of the common reasons employees leave a company.

**Just figure it out - Cons:**

- (Employer) Higher staff turnover
- (Employer) Harder to find good employees that care about their career and improving
- (Employee) Doesn't matter how hard you work, promotions seem due to chance or social popularity
- (Employee) Demotivating when a colleague is promoted over you for no apparent reason
- (Employee) The wrong people can be promoted over those who really deserve it
- (Employee) Nothing to aim for

**Career Progression Policy - Pros:**

- (Employer) Higher staff retention
- (Employee) Something to work towards. Keeps you motivated to improve
- (Employee) Almost guaranteed promotion when requirements are met
- (Employee) No resentment when others are promoted
- (Employee) You know what is required if you want a promotion

**Career Progression Policy - Cons:**

- (Employer) Have to give promotion if employees meet the requirement
- (Employer) Have to spend time writing policies
- (Employer) Have to spend time with performance reviews

Comment: *"There isn't a single pro for the employee."* What about: Managers can promote people who are actually best for the job instead of those who successfully game the system? Might be relevant for some industries. I can't find the link right now, but I remember a question here or on one of the sister SE sites recently which basically concluded that there are no metrics that can successfully and reliably measure software developer performance.

Comment: One thing to look out for with progression policies: Some companies put minimum/maximum tenures on promotions.  Depending on the policy, you might excel in all other areas but be denied a promotion due to a lack of "hours on the clock", or you might put in the bare minimum effort and be promoted simply due to company loyalty.  This could be either a pro or a con depending on your work ethic, but I would be wary of such policies because it can have a big impact on company culture.

Comment: You have clearly never seen the promotion policies in German government positions. There's a lot of pros of no policy vs. a bad policy. Actually, you are comparing a bad implementation of "no policy" to a good implementation of "policy" to reach your conclusion. That's foul play.

Comment: "There isn't a single pro for the employee" seems to be contradicted by "Doesn't matter how hard you work, promotions seem due to [...] social popularity". If you *are* the popular type of employee, this is clearly an advantage since it means you can get a promotion by selling your work internally. Sure not good for all employees, but if the opposite is a negative for some then this is a positive for some others.

Comment: Another factor is bias - a "just figure it out" approach leaves the door open for managers' bias (racial, gender, age, etc) to impact who gets promoted. That said, a bad policy leaves the door open for the policy designer/implementer to systemically encode their biases into it.

Comment: By this logic, unionized companies with a rigid promotion system, especially public sector promotion-grid type of arrangements are the best ever place to work.  This seems rather one-sided, doesn't it?

Comment: A "promotion policy" doesn't have to be rigid. That is an implementation detail and up to companies how they do it... You can still have a policy, use common sense and make exceptions

Comment: You don't "have to" promote employees who meet the requirements. You definitely should, but you can probably also indefinitely delay that by citing budget concerns or awaiting approval from upper management or whatever, or simply refusing to appraise them fairly on the more subjective criteria so they can never meet the criteria (I don't know about you, but in my career to date most to all career progression policy items were quite subjective).

Comment: "Just figure it out" has another pro that it's easier to promote employees for different reasons that may not be able to fit into a concrete policy. For employees this could be beneficial if the reasons for promotion is based on who is highly valuable to the company (e.g. working on highly profitable or complex projects or problems). This could be especially relevant if you have specialists who share job titles with generalists or with specialists in other areas.

Comment: @Heinzi Policies don't need to be algorithmically rigid (and they definitely should not). You can (easily) game a system only if it is too rigid to have common-sense and safeguards built-in. OTOH Leaving people in the dark is prone to one of the worst kind of gamification: corruption and nepotism (which plague many Italian companies, public and private as well, even today)....

Comment: @Heinzi ...  As an example: some 20y ago a close friend of mine (then a brilliant young engineer in a managing role in a recently privatized huge telecom company) was doing extremely well (she even managed the restructuring of Bolivia's then ancient telephone network). After some years of not seeing any advancement, she saw one of her young intern (who didn't even have a degree) and son of a national-level politician to be "installed" as her team project-manager. Yeah, great thing not having a policy!

Comment: @LorenzoDonati--Codidact.com: I never claimed that "no policy" was strictly better than having a policy, just that it *can* be beneficial for employees as well. I agree that having a policy makes nepotism a bit harder, although it's (unfortunately) no silver bullet. We have the same problem here in Austria, and you'd be surprised of the creative workarounds employed to get around those policies in close-to-government companies (e.g. writing the job ad in a way that ensures that only the specific person they *want* to get the job satisfies all requirements).

Comment: @Heinzi, sorry for giving the impression that I criticized your comment as a whole (I actually "upvoted" it). I just wanted to stress-out that "gamification" could be even worse in "absolutely no-policy" systems. But it seems we mostly agree on the bottom line. And yep, I sadly know how those ad-hoc "requirement documents" look like, not only for jobs ad but even for public tenders (I live in South Tirol, and that kind of trick is common here). Sigh!

Comment: @Heinzi If we can learn anything from Economics, it is that people act in accordance with their incentives.  When there is no clear incentive to promote people according to merits, a "no promotion policy" (which is actually a kind of promotion policy) expands to include selfish reasons of promoting the like-minded, the flattery experts, the closely related, those who are undeserving yet hold information that could be damaging, and all other manners of less than ideal managers; because the policy permits it, and motivation comes from reasons other than those permitted by policy.

Answer (score 8):

Flexi has a great answer that covers most things. I just wanted to add this.

**There is always a promotion policy.**

Companies do not exist in a vacuum, as much as many think they do for the purposes of employment. The generalized promotion policy varies by industry, but at least in tech, it is generate a resume, pass a technical interview, pass a behavioral interview, and maybe pass another technical interview.

Left to their own devices, you can expect a lot of employees to take the default option.

You basically need to bet that employees would rather "figure it out" instead of taking the defined path (which always exists in one form or another). That to me is the largest con, albeit with the bias that as an engineer, I much prefer a process I can break down to one that is messy and not rule based.

Comment: I've red this question a few times and don't understand "There is always a promotion policy". It seems to contradict the other answers and the premise of the question. How do you mean it, is it in the sense "our policy is no policy"?

Comment: @finjjj it depends on the industry, but employees effectively work in an industry, not for one particular company. If I have no idea how to get a promotion at my current company, I can just go to a different one.

Comment: @finjjj, it means that the middle and upper managers know what gets people promoted, but it is not written down.

Answer (score 5):

> I was recently hired to be a manager at a new company and during my onboarding I was told that there isn't really a promotion process here and it is expected that worthwhile employees will figure it out.

Let me translate that for you:

> We don't know how to properly promote people so it is easier to not even try. We think this has worked so far. The people who fight tooth and nail will eventually get recognized, I think; err at least they will once somebody higher up quits.
>
> Filling your position with an external candidate should be enough evidence as to how well our "organic" approach works.

---

> Is this an accurate perception?

It's **their** perception, yes.

---

> Do companies do better if they have promotion policies or do they do better if they have a more organic approach?

[See flexi's excellent answer.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/173651/17532)

Answer (score 0):

> I was recently hired to be a manager at a new company and during my onboarding I was told that there isn't really a promotion process here and it is expected that worthwhile employees will figure it out.

I would question the implicit assumption that the skills required to figure out the workings of an undocumented, informal promotion process are closely correlated with the skills required to be a valuable employee. There might be some workplaces where this is true due to the nature of the work, but there's no obvious reason to believe this as a general principle. To be blunt, it sounds like optimism.

There's also a question about how much time you want employees to spend trying to figure out that process, vs. just being able to point them at the documentation. This one comes down partly to elements of scale - for a small business that only needs to deal with these issues occasionally, an ad-hoc process might be less effort, but for a large one there's more benefit in standardisation.

(There is also an issue of whether a candidate's ability to *game* the process correlates well with their value as an employee, but that's an issue for both formal and informal processes, albeit in different ways.)

I will note that a formal promotion process doesn't automatically mean depending on KPIs or other such gameable metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is always a policy; this one is based on the secret whims of middle and upper managers, combined with the clout of each manager.

That's the current policy, and should be the baseline for comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that whether companies “do better” or not has less to do with the specific binary bit of “promotion policy/no promotion policy”, and a lot more to do with whether the company is well-managed overall and has a healthy company culture.

Now, in particular, “well-managed” and “healthy culture” mean a company where management doesn’t give BS explanations to employees and middle managers for why it does things. And the explanation “it is expected that worthwhile employees figure it out” that you were given sounds like just that — BS. To believe that it was offered in good faith, you have to believe that the person who told you this thinks that the set of skills that makes a good employee who is deserving of promotion coincides with the ability to “figure it out” and manage to get a promotion by being savvy about company politics, knowing who are the right people to impress/suck up to, and assert yourself as being worthy of promoting. But this is an obvious fallacy. And as @flexi’s answer illustrates (notwithstanding some of the valid criticisms against it offered in the comments), the overwhelmingly more plausible explanation for why the company doesn’t have a promotion policy are that either management is too lazy or incompetent to come up with such a policy, or they believe that not having a policy stacks the deck in their favor and allows them to underpay good employees. As @flexi explained, this is short-termist thinking.

TLDR: there are probably some decent or even good arguments in favor of not having a promotion policy — assuming that decision was made on a rational basis in a way that’s consistent with many other rational decisions and in the context of the company’s specific culture/industry/situation — but the one you were offered is quite clearly not one of them.